Can I converse with someone using a Google Home Smart Speaker via Google Home app?
My mother has early stage Alzheimer's. She still lives alone but I want to be able to communicate with her and keep an eye on her remotely.
A few years ago I installed some Google Nest cameras around her house (with her permission) that I view via the Google home app. These cameras have been very helpful for visually keeping an eye on her.
I now would like to be able to converse with her using the Google home app. The Nest cameras do have the ability for conversing (in other words, they have a built in microphone and small speaker) but she is hard of hearing so she can't hear the tiny speaker on the Nest cameras.
So I would like to install a speaker (with a built in microphone) of higher volume ability that I can use via Google Home app to converse with her.
From my internet research it seems that the Google Home Smart Speaker fits this description: A speaker (with a microphone) that can be controlled via the Google Home app.
But, despite my searching the internet for answers, I can't seem to find out if it will allow me to converse with her using my Google Home app.
So that is my question: If I purchase a Google Home Smart Speaker and add it to my Google Home app, will I be able to use it to converse with my mom via my Google home app, just as if we were having a phone conversation?

The Nest Hub Max used to be able to make/receive Duo/Google Meet video calls. This would allow you to have a conversation from your phone.
It looks like you can enable Google Meet calls on a Nest Mini under the settings for the device in the Goolge Home App as well.
